# How to query google maps place web service API nearby search with multiple name terms?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

In the google maps place API web service doc it says for nearbySearch for name "One or more terms to be matched against the names of places, separated with a space character."

But I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried the following

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=AIzaSyDi9shpQeCKw2VyelOJrawc****&location=41.8369,-87.6847&radius=50000&name=alinea%20yusho

but it returns no results even though google definitely has entries for both alinea and yusho. What exactly do they mean by "separated with a space character"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use pipe symbol instead. I tried it and it worked!

```
name=alinea|yusho
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works for me. On a side note you can also do it for keywords with the following syntax: keyword=("yusho") OR ("alinea"). The documentation does not mention this anywhere.